# How to find all artifacts added to Sonatype Nexus in the last 24 hours?

Tags: nexus

How do I get a list of all artifacts that were added to the **Sonatype Nexus central repository** within the last 24 hours?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest parsing the RSS feeds provided by Nexus:

- http://www.sonatype.com/books/nexus-book/reference/using-sect-feeds.html

Comment: Thanks, but I get "Authentication Required" (https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/feeds/recentlyChangedFiles)

Comment: @stephanos That's a pity. Perhaps raise a ticket to the Sonatype folks and see if they'd provide a public feed. Must be a pretty common request.

Comment: @stephanos +1 Excellent followup